# Обособление обстоятельства времени в начале предложения

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, обстоятельство

«С начала зарождения жизни на Земле(,) существовал параллельный мир, который был доступен единицам».
Нужна ли запятая и почему?

Comment: Предложение желательно редактировать.  Его структура не очень удачная, так что о запятой сложно говорить. Запятая здесь факультативная и зависит от структуры.

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, что не так со структурой предложения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Если не обособлять, то получатся две фразы: ***С начала зарождения жизни на Земле** / существовал параллельный мИр // который был доступен единИцам.*

Структура вполне приемлема, но смысл странный – предложение похоже на **начало** повествования, а я не уверена, что это так.

2. Если оборот обособить, то получатся три фразы:  ***С начала зарождения жИзни на Земле,** // существовал параллельный мИр// который был доступен единИцам.*

Смысл такой: Когда зародилась жизнь на Земле, существовал параллельный мир… Тоже звучит странно.

3. Возможный вариант (надо проверять по контексту):  *Параллельный мир существовал **с начала зарождения жИзни на Земле**, но был тогда доступен единицам.*

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно понял суть предложения, ***запятая не нужна, но фразу надо править***.

Причина требуемой правки: в исходном виде смысл не очень понятен. И дело не "параллельном мире" и прочем оккультизме, плохо понимаемом всеми, кроме его непосредственных апологетов (о чем, похоже, говорит @Sharon). Тут чисто формальные причины.
**"Зарождение"- это момент**, точка на временн**о**й оси, у него нет ни начала ни конца. Возможно, именно это и вызывает сомнения в пунктуации.

Советы:
~1. Фразу править в связи вышеизложенным, в исходном виде она просто неприемлема. Заодно и "мир, который доступен" заменить на что-то более осмысленное.

***С момента возникновения жизни на Земле существовал параллельный мир, понимание которого (или посещение которого, знание о котором, котнакт с которым... и т. д.) было доступно только единицам.***

Говоря честно, все равно не очень здорово выглядит, но я боюсь дальнейшей правкой убить авторский смысл, который до конца мне не ясен.

~2. Обособление "с момента возникновения жизни" не требуется. Ни вводным, ни уточняющим членом эта конструкция не является, а других причин вообще не просматривается.
Сравните с аналогичной по грамматической структуре фразой: ***"С утра светило Солнце."*** *Вряд ли кому придет в голову ставит запятую после "С утра"?!*
В этом @ЕгорСальков прав, хотя, к сожалению, его ответ слишком краток.

Answer (score 1):

Не нужна. Почему не нужна? Потому, что для её постановки нет причин.